# Android Relative layout hides my images view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-relativelayout

I have a grid view. and I have simple grid adapter with custom view,
But that custom view hides image but I can see view in Eclipse graphical layout view. but when I run it, it hides an image

```
    custom grid item layout :

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/grid_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridviewlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/grid_item_selector" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/text"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="settings"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If these are the only components in your layout then your root tag `linearLayout` seems meaningless to me, remove it.

Comment: As @Apurva correctly noted, you have a **useless** (and it is bad for performances) `layout nesting`. Please, remove the LinearLayout parent.

Comment: thank u @Apurva but actually linear layout used to change bg color dynamically and relaltive has selector, so that I need to use Linear layout...
because with dynamic color I unable to change bg color no??
so that Linear used..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your error log for custom grid item layout xml , I have check your code with sample it give me output.
**May be your images has been corrupted**. checked your drawable/ic_launcher file or your resources folder replace with another image and try it.

Comment: Hey thank u very much...I got an answer...
The ic_launcher was corrupted..thank u

Answer (score 0):

Please share the image what kind of view you want and. As you are using `RelativeLayout` it will surely hide some views
-`Layout_rightof,Layout_above` by setting these properties you can set the views appropriately

`For example:`

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgMenu"
        android:layout_width="..."
        android:layout_height="..."
        android:layout_gravity="..."
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_key"
        ... />

    <TextView
        android:id="..."
        android:layout_width="..."
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgMenu"
        android:layout_height="..."
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
          />
```

Above contents shows `Textview` is right of my `ImageView`.

-Hello try your Imageview Fixed height and width check what happens.

Comment: I unable to post image as I have less reputation...so

Comment: and you can see that layout has simple code, only some properties are there

Comment: But because of Relative layout in your code it is hiding your imageview set it properly!

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove Unnecessary `LinearLayout`.
2. Wrap your `ImageView` by `FrameLayout` as:

   ```
   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="48dp"
       android:layout_height="48dp"
       android:layout_above="@+id/text"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       >

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/picture"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"  
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
           android:padding="5dp"
           android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

   </FrameLayout>
   ```

Hope this help!

Comment: Actually that linear layout used to change background color...
relative layout has selector and linear has only back color.

Comment: And I used ur code of that frame layout but still it shows same output...
It hides that imageview

Comment: can you try `frameLayout` with specific size, look my answer